# Copy/paste only contents (pictures) from browser

Tags: browser

When I copy contents from a browser, and try to paste it into Word or a similar recipient, it tries to bring in all the HTML tags (links, inputs, buttons, etc).

Is there a convenient way of pasting only contents, equivalent to pasting "values" - but in this case it would paste text and pictures only without the links and the rest of the garbage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the text only is usually pretty easy into Word.  Simply paste with the shortcut CTRL-SHIFT-V (or click paste special).

I don't know of any way to get the images in addition to the text without getting all the rest of the formatting.

Comment: To get the unformatted text, you could also paste into a plain-text editor like Notepad, then copy it from there. (I usually use the Run dialog for single lines of text.)

Comment: Yes, I know for the text part. I guess my true question is how to do for pictures.